# Why is my rpmbuild %{dist} .fc30.fc30 instead of just .fc30?

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a `.spec` file:

```
Name:           somefile
Version:        1.0.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
...
```

Which produces an RPM:

`somefile-1.0.0-1.fc30.fc30.noarch.rpm`

Why is `%{dist}` applying `.fc30` twice? If I remove `%{dist}` then I end up with a file:

`somefile-1.0.0-1.noarch.rpm`

The value of `%{dist}`, according to rpm is just `.fc30`, as expected:

```
$ rpm --eval %{dist}
.fc30
```

---

**UPDATE**

It seems to duplicate the last part no matter what it is:

```
Release:        1.123
```

This gave me a file: `somefile-1.0.0-1.123.123.noarch.rpm`.

---

**UPDATE**

This seems to be a result of the dist macro:

```
$ rpm --showrc | grep ' dist'
-13: dist   %{?distprefix}.fc30%{?with_bootstrap:~bootstrap}
```

Am I using it wrong?

Comment: What does `rpm --eval %_rpmfilename` say? Does that give you any hints? Try to follow the fields from there and expand them with `rpm --eval` to see if you find which one is duplicating the last field...

Comment: It says: `%{ARCH}/%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}.rpm`

Comment: Does the specfile itself redefine any RPM macros such as `_rpmfilename`? How are you building the RPM, are you using `rpmbuild -ba` directly or are you using a wrapper around it (which could be passing additional options)?

Comment: I am using `rpmbuild` directly with no wrapper. I did not redefine any variables.

Comment: Yes... But is there any `%define` *inside* `somefile.spec`?

Comment: Also, if you inspect the RPM file itself (with `rpm -qpi somefile-1.0.0-1.fc30.fc30.noarch.rpm`, do you see the duplication in the "Release:" field? In other words, is release `1.fc30` or is it `1.fc30.fc30`?

Comment: Or also `%global` is also possible to set rpm macros...

Comment: Run rpm --showrc | grep dist to see which macros play with dist value.

Comment: @msuchy The `dist` macro appears to be: `%{?distprefix}.fc30%{?with_bootstrap:~bootstrap}`.